# How to implement a 'Cache then network' strategy using Workbox

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm trying to implemement a ['cache then network'](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#cache-then-network) strategy using Workbox.

I've set Workbox to use the [`staleWhileRevalidate`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-runtime-caching.StaleWhileRevalidate) runtimeCaching handler, but I'm not sure how best to update the page once/if the cache us updated from the network.

The docs say:

> In addition to updating the appropriate caches, it will also trigger any appropriate plugins defined in the underlying RequestWrapper.

Would that be any use? Are there any examples of this strategy being done with Workbox (which, by the way, is a wonderful tool, so thank you to its maintainers)?

Comment: I am fairly sure I need to use `cacheDidUpdate`, but I'm not sure how to and haven't been able to find any examples so far.

Comment: Looking at the [offline cookbook entry](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#cache-then-network) again, perhaps this is best done outside of the service worker, by interacting with the cache API directly from the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example of using the `BroadcastCacheUpdate` functionality in a "standalone" fashion at https://workbox-samples.glitch.me/examples/workbox-broadcast-cache-update/

To use it along with `staleWhileValidate` via WorkboxSW's routing, you could do something like:

```
workboxSW.router.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/some/path/prefix'),
  workboxSW.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'my-cache',
    broadcastUpdate: {
      channelName: 'my-update-channel'
    },
  })
);
```

You can see a complete example in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-sw.Strategies#.StrategyOptions).

Comment: Ah, that's wonderful. I had forgotten there were so many examples on Glitch (and really well commented too). Thank you so much :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jeffposnick/a8f7662b5d4677566c22b1cb82e6ec5f looks relevant too (thanks Jeff)